# R ggplot2: manually set fill colour without "fill" aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose a violin plot created using ggplot2 with only one factor (on the horizontal axis). This plot shows colorless violins as the single factor is used for the x-axis.

For example, this quick MWE:

```
oneplot <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
  geom_violin()
oneplot
```

Is it possible afterwards to set the fill colours? In my actual setting, the plot is generated through a large procedure in charge of multiple things and it does not assign a "fill" aesthetics; it just delivers a plot that can be changed post-hod with additional graphic directives such as `scale_fill_manual`.

I was hoping that I could add some directives, e.g.,

```
oneplot + scale_fill_manual(breaks = c(0.5,1,2), values = c("orange", "purple","blue"))
```

but for the moment, the fillings stay utterly colorless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the specific result you were looking for (which is really just a follow-on from Axeman's excellent answer) is:

```
oneplot + 
  aes(fill = factor(dose)) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c(0.5,1,2), values = c("orange", "purple","blue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Not very well known, but you can use `aes` as an additive plot component too.

So:

```
oneplot <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=factor(dose), y=len)) +
  geom_violin()
oneplot
```

[image]

```
oneplot + aes(fill = supp)
```

[image]

This does assume that your fill variable is present in the data, so `supp` must be present in `ToothGrowth`. However, we can update the data component too, using the special operater `%+%`:

```
oneplot %+% filter(ToothGrowth, dose < 2) + aes(fill = supp)
```

[image]

These techniques can be very useful when making slight variations of the same plot. Define the large structure once, then update the data or aesthetics for each plot.